# How to elegantly show the direction in this specific situation?

Tags: conversation

Given a map like the following:

[image]

Now your friend is standing at 1 end of the street 1 & he want to go to school.

*How can you elegantly show him the direction?*

Here is what I suggest but it is a bit cumbersome.

```
-Go Straight
-And Go past the corner between Street 1 & 2
-Keep going straight
-Turn left into the street 3
-Go straight
-Turn right into the Street 4
-Go straight & turn left to street 5
-Go straight until you can see the school
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Straight on *Street 1*, then turn left on *Street 3*, right on *Street 4*, left on *Street 5*.  The school will be down *Street 5* on the right.

This may not be the elegance you are looking for, but I have found that the fewer words one uses to give directions, the more likely the recipient is to actually remember.

Comment: Including *go past *Street 2* could be added for more information.

Answer (score 3):

There are any number of ways of giving directions, but if I were in this situation, I'd say something like:

> Keep going straight on Street 1 until you get to Street 3.
>   Turn left on Street 3.
>   Street 3 makes a sharp right turn and becomes Street 4.
>   Take the first left from Street 4 onto Street 5; the school will be on your right.

I might also give directions using cardinal directions.  If the person I was giving directions to seemed to understand them clearly, I would probably shorten the directions a bit as well:

> Head south on Street 1, then turn east on Street 3.  
>   Take Street 3 until it runs into Street 4, headed south.
>   Turn east onto Street 5; the school is on the south side of the road.

Note that "head" is a verb here, it means to travel in the direction that follows.  Also when giving directions, we might say "take a {direction or street}" instead of "turn {direction} or go {on a street}."

It never really occurred to me before, but there is a whole set of idioms and slang that go along with direction-giving.  I have to think it's going to vary from region to region, so for your information, I'm from the US Midwest.

Comment: Can you try to use these terms only "*Go straight*", "*turn left into*", "*turn right into*", & "*go past*"?

Comment: @Tom Sure, though you would say "turn left/right **onto**" rather than **into**.  You don't really need to tell people to go past intersections.  That is assumed.  Something like "Go straight on St. 1 until you get to St. 3.  Turn left onto St. 3.  Turn right onto St. 4.  Turn left onto St. 5."